# strange performance difference running rust code in powershell vs cmd

Tags: powershell, rust

I have a non trivial rust app. The piece I am talking about loads ~500k of text, parses that text and loads it into a sqlite database. I put a timer in that piece of code to show the difference

When I run the app from Powershell in Windows terminal on Windows 11

I get

```
PS C:\work\db65> .\target\debug\db65.exe
db65 0.1.5 (65e48f8)
>> ll ft.dbg
version
information
lib
csyms: 67
files: 116
lines: 4655
modules: 81
segments: 9
spans: 3320
scopes: 143
symbols: 1503
it took 5401 milli seconds
>>
```

~5 seconds to parse and load. However when I run the same binary by starting cmd from start menu i get

```
C:\work\db65>target\debug\db65.exe
db65 0.1.5 (65e48f8)
>> ll ft.dbg
version
information
lib
csyms: 67
files: 116
lines: 4655
modules: 81
segments: 9
spans: 3320
scopes: 143
symbols: 1503
it took 210 milli seconds
>>
```

Thats about 20 times  faster!

Its the same binary run with the same command line options.

I have no idea what to look at to try to fix this.

Note that if in powershell I do

```
PS C:\work\db65> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2861]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\work\db65>target\debug\db65.exe
db65 0.1.5 (65e48f8)
```

its still slow

Comment: What is the exact command line you're starting from the shell, and what does VSCode report as the exact command line it is executing for you?

Comment: Maybe it's a power shell overhead. What is the time if it can be run under a cmd shell?

Comment: Seems pretty moot to compare debug builds performance.

Comment: @grismar - its there as the first line of the first sample run , no args. I dont know how to ask vscode what args it used, but I included the launch.json to show the command line i asked for

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison - ran under cmd, the same result

Comment: @cafce25 - just ran release build. 3 seconds in shell, 93 ms in vscode

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison - OMG, I was running cmd from PS. Tried running cmd directly from start - release now takes 57 ms!

Comment: @pm100: Something tells me this isn't going to be solvable for the general case, it's going to be specific to your machine or your program; there's no reason a command that isn't involved in PowerShell pipes should have multiple seconds of different runtime measured from *within* the program (I'd get taking longer measured from launch time to return to prompt, as PowerShell could delay launching and/or the appearance of a new prompt with the extra features and somewhat slower .NET implementation). But none of that seems like it should affect the program time once launched.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I am trying to think where to start looking. This app will be run from PS command line when run on windows, having a 20x slowdown is simply not acceptable. Any pointers?. I dont think its sqlite, I saw the same slowness when I was parsing into memory. I was wondering about env variables, PS does odd managment of them , some rust code read them.

Comment: @pm100: I think Rust delegates environment variable access to the OS-equivalent of `getenv`, and most of the work involved there is done before your code starts, and wouldn't cause seconds of slowdown.

Comment: The best way to help us help you would be to [write a simpler app that exhibits the same behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If that's not feasible: try with a smaller input size (eg. 5K files), then use [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to record and spot any obvious differences in runtime behavior - number of I/O operations performed, repeated registry reads, unexpected delays etc.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - at the moment I am working through removeing crate dependencies, ie hand coding csv parsing, etc. Seems to make no difference. I will try to create a minimal repro the code is pretty isolated, I already used procmon too see if there was anything suspicious, nada

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - i have a free standing , one file version, its still 900 lines tho. I am out of ideas. If you feeling like looking I can put it and the input file in my repo

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I had Env:RUST_BACKTRACE=1 in my main PS shell

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Env:RUST_BACKTRACE was set to 1 :-(

Answer (score 4):

Well, TIL that having `$Env:RUST_BACKTRACE=1` is VERY , VERY expensive. Or, of course, the regular equivalent in whatever shell you use.

Superliminal performance explorer (https://superluminal.eu/rust/) found it immediately.